# Alternatives to Google's weighted sort for binomial experiments with n=1

Tags: binomial-distribution, ranking

An interesting data scientist interview question:

"We are looking at the failure rate for opening files on websites for many clients. We want to rank the files by failure rate; but, with our current method, the files that have been only opened once (and failed) rise to the top of the rank. What statistical method would you use to get around this?

What statistical methods would you use to rank the file load failure rate so that files with only one open do not rise to the top?"

They really liked Google's weighted sort that is described here https://moz.com/blog/build-your-own-weighted-sort

I have my own thoughts on this question; but, I would like to hear what the community thinks.

Comment: I'm really interested in your thoughts on this. This is a really exciting problem! What are your thoughts on this question?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I was thinking of a Bayes approach (also mentioned in your link).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't a standard solution to this problem just be some kind of credibility factor? For example say $f(n)$ with your weighted average being $f(n) \bar{x}_i + (1-f(n)) \bar{x}$. Where $\bar{x}_i$ is the mean of the observations and $\bar{x}$ is the mean of the population.

The google example is one. There is also the [Buhlmann Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BChlmann_model). In order to make this work I believe $f(n)$ should be bounded between 0 and 1 and should not be decreasing with $n$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I ended up using your formula with f(n) = (number of file dls for site x)/(number of file dls for all sites) for its simplicity.